# Issues with high CPU utilization on a Surface Pro 3

Tags: cpu, overheating, microsoft-surface-pro-3, high-cpu-usage, utilization

Currently problems being faced constantly is really high CPU demand which is leading to overheating issues in my Surface Pro 3.

I have conducted a Power Efficiency Diagnostics Report to understand the problems. From the analysis Results I have encountered a “CPU Utilisation:Processor utilisation is high” error with an Average Utilisation (%) of 29.71 and therefore have carried out the process of obtaining a `HighCPUUsage.etl` report [which is downloadable for review here](http://1drv.ms/1EiUYpL). Understanding the report is where I find it difficult to assess the current issues with the CPU.

Could anyone please suggest the right path to take in obtaining a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the latest firmware and drivers: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=38826

https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/install-update-activate/pro-3-update-history?os=windows-8.1-update-1

The ETL trace indicates issue with: ACPI.sys -> ACPI.sys!OSNotifyDeviceWake -> ACPI.sys!ACPIWakeRemoveDevicesAndUpdate -> hal.dll!HalpAcpiPmRegisterWritePort

This is indicative of power management problems. Change the OS power plan/power options for devices.

Looking at event viewer for Kernel-Power events may also be helpful